# How to render long html string with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to use selenium to render the html of a request without having to save it on a file. I'm open to other ideas to solve this problem.

I need to render the html to save it with generated tags like `<tbody>` for example.

I tried to inject the html like data to the driver, but for long html code it doesn't work.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

html_test = '''<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <td><tr>
        Hellow work
      </tr></td>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>'''

driver.get(f'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_test}')
rendered_html = driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

This code works with small samples of html, but not with a full page code.

Comment: What error do you get with a full page of code?

Comment: Why not setup a webserver and point selenium to that?

Comment: No error, selenium simply loads empty page

Comment: Do you have an example of a longer string you would use that yields nothing?

Comment: For example: `html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')`

Comment: You could try navigating to a standard page, and then use Selenium to execute javacript to populate it.

Comment: I tried to do that loading an empty html file first and then injecting code with `#driver.execute_script(f"document.innerHTML = '{html}';")`, but it doesn't work, maybe I missed something?